# C++11 std::atomic_fetch_add vs __sync_fetch_and_add

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm currently having troubles correctly understanding the usage of the new `std::atomic` types. For my case I have the following assumptions:

1. I have a contiguous memory location of `uint64_t` values stored in memory
2. I have two kinds of accesses simple increments and atomic increments

Originally I implemented the methods like this

```
uint64_t inc(const size_t pos) { return _data[pos]++; }
uint64_t atomic_inc(const size_t pos) { return __sync_fetch_and_add(&_data[pos], 1); }
```

Now I wanted to port this correctly to C++11 and was wondering how should I handle this correctly. From my understanding of [std::atomic_fetch_add](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_fetch_add) one basically needs an atomic integral value to do this. However, how do I need to implement this correctly, so that I can point using an atomic variable to a location and increment the value?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you maybe be bit more precise about your problem? You can treat a `std::atomic` like a normal int, even the operators are overloaded for the normal usecases.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, you want _data  to be a normal uint64 and pos to be the atomic variable or both of them to be atomic? I threw together a simple example here http://ideone.com/7RqlwP . As bamboon said you can increment atomic variables both normally and atomically.

Comment: You have to jump through extra hoops to get non-atomic increment. The overloaded operators are equivalent to corresponding `atomic_fetch_*op*` calls

Comment: Consider having an array of integer values and you want to increment the value at a certain offset. But not necessarily all accesses to this array require an atomic increment or enforced memory order. The question is, can this be handled in a single data structure or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

A C++11 atomic object encapsulates its base type. It does not provide access to its value as lvalue nor can you set it up to provide atomic operations on a preexisting object of the underlying type (at a given memory location).

Depending on the platform any given atomic type might have special requirements (e.g. stronger alignment constraints) or need auxiliary data (most atomic types are not guaranteed to be lock-free)

Doing what you want to do still requires platform-specific functionality.

If you want to do non-atomic increments,the closest you can get is:

```
  atomic<uint64_t> data(initial_value);
  data.store(data.load(memory_order_relaxed) + 1, memory_order_relaxed);
```

This will still do atomic loads and stores, but no memory fencing or atomic read-modify-write operations.

Answer (score 9):

You cannot use C++11 facilities to get atomic access to a variable that is not declared as an atomic type. You would need to replace your array of `uint64_t` with an array of `std::atomic<uint64_t>`. On many platforms, this will have the same size and alignment as plain `uint64_t`, but all operations will be atomic.

You can then use `data[pos].fetch_add(1,memory_order)` to do the atomic increment with the specified `memory_order`. If you need a memory order of `std::memory_order_seq_cst` (which is probably the closest to the GCC `__sync_fetch_and_add`), then the memory order can be omitted, or you could use an increment operator, e.g. `data[pos]++`.